# Why is next.js Image component not converting the svg to .webp file?

Tags: javascript, svg, next.js

### Context

So I created a simple Hero + Navbar in Next.js. I use next.js `Image` component. On all my images on the site (i think 3 in total) the size is 0B and gets loaded instantly. They are of type `.webp` - so next.js image did convert these files.

### The problem

In the navbar I have my logo which is a SVG of 2KB. I used this the same way I used the other .png files, but this time it's a .svg
In the browser the file doesn't shrink and it's still a type of .svg and not .webp. Why is that?

Here is a screenshot how I use it:

[image]

Here is the network tab (filtered on images).

[image]

I import the svg file in the page like this `import logoDark from "../public/assets/Logon New.svg"`

Am I doing something wrong? Why is next.js not making a very fast .webp?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-part answer:

### Why you do not need SVG's further optimized

There is no need to take SVG's and convert them to a raster format. Vector format's are *usually* optimal and offer lossless scaling unless desktop programs added more meta data and bloated the file - even this can be rectified using tools like  https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

### `next/image` leaving SVG’s unoptimized:

The documentation shows why `svg` files are left alone

> The default loader does not optimize SVG images for a few reasons. First, SVG is a vector format meaning it can be resized losslessly. Second, SVG has many of the same features as HTML/CSS, which can lead to vulnerabilities without proper Content Security Policy (CSP) headers.

> If you need to serve SVG images with the default Image Optimization API, you can set dangerouslyAllowSVG and contentSecurityPolicy inside your next.config.js:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#dangerously-allow-svg

Comment: Thx very nice explained. Everything makes sense now.